How to fix module not running on python jupyter notebook in visual studio code. I need the code
{
"name": "",
"message": "",
"stack": "Failed to start the Kernel.
Unable to start Kernel 'Python 3.12.2' due to a timeout waiting for the ports to get used.
View Jupyter log for further details."
}
I am expecting import pandas to work on the jupyter notebook in visual studio

you can select a python environment on the top right hand side by "clicking on the yellow section".
once you open the .ipynb file (you must have python installed for this)

Make sure you have the pandas library installed.
installing the pandas library
cell:
pip install pandas
py -m pip install pandas
terminal
pip install pandas
py -m pip - install pandas
py pip install pandas

The cell command for installing Pandas in a running Jupyter .ipynb file would be best stated explicitly as %pip install pandas. And then the kernel should be restarted after running that. (For other, more complex installs, not Pandas, Jupyter and the browser will need to be entirely restarted.) The convenient magic command works essentially universally now and eliminate the complexity you are introducing with suggesting py -m pip install pandas. (First, I think you need an exclamation point for running that in a cell. Second...

 That command isn't easy to understand what it is doing and on some systems is !python -m pip install pandas or !python3 -m pip install pandas, etc..) The magic %pip install command insures the install occurs in the same environment where the active kernel is running that is backing the running Jupyter .ipynb file. And encourages avoiding using exclamation point for installs. See more about the modern %pip install command that is current best practice here.
